# Excel - shortcut to get me back after clicking a link

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel document that has more sheets and those sheets link to each other using textual hyperlinks (*Insert Hyperlink > Place in This Document*).

When I click such hyperlink, it takes me to another sheet (or, more specifically, to a certain cell in that sheet). **Is there a way to quickly navigate back?** I tried to add the "Back" command to the Quick Access Toolbar but it is grayed out after navigation.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked for me. I did need to add the `Back` and `Forward` buttons to the quick bar. Are you sure you did that? The `Back` button looks very similar to the `Undo` button.

Comment: @krowe, where are the back and forward buttons (I'm on Excel 2010 here and can't find them)?

Comment: Ohh, this is tagged 2013. If you have the ribbon it is the same though. Just go to ribbon editor (select `More Commands` on the dropdown to the right) and in the dialog select the `All Commands` option in the dropdown. Then look for `Back` and `Forward`.

Comment: Borek, can you create a new Excel file, add a single navigation (and the back button) and try again - as per Krowe's comments, it works for me so I'm wondering if there is something else on your worksheet preventing it

Comment: It works in an empty Excel file - maybe it had something to do with the fact that the problematic Excel file was downloaded from the internet and not enabled for editing. I don't quite understand why that would prevent the Back command to work but ok, strange things sometimes happen in the land of Microsoft :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to `Quick Access Toolbar` editor (select `More Commands` on the dropdown to the
   right of it).
2. In the subsequent dialog select the `All Commands` option in the
   dropdown control.
3. Then look for the `Back` and `Forward` options. Double click them to add them to the `Quick Access Toolbar`.

[image: Screenshot showing each step]

Note that the `Undo` button, which is on the `Quick Access Toolbar` bar by default, looks very similar to the `Back` button.

Comment: Great answer. Without your screenshot I would never have found how to do this trivial task.  I'd repeatedly visited this dialogue but missed  'All commands'.    Someone needs to  try to be less 'clever'